# Create looping scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll

I created this script for simple scroll of news. My problem is I don't know how I can create a loop in the scroll.

For example when the scroll goes to the end it stops.  I want the scroll to start again. When it goes to the end start another time and continue forever.

**My script :**

```
function scroll_cp(id,time)
{
    var div = $('#'+id);
    setInterval(function(){
        var pos = div.scrollTop();
        div.scrollTop(pos + 2);
    }, time)
}
```

Thank´s for the help

Comment: Can you explain which way you want it to scroll as there are several options? Better still create a JSFiddle or supply some HTML to go with the JQuery.

Comment: use `window.scroll()` .

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.scroll(x-coord, y-coord)`
**[More Info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.scroll)**